# How can i create column with information about who Created an element

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Can you help me. How can i create column with information about who Created  an element(column CreatedBy) I created asp net core 2.0 MVC Web-Application with Windows authentication. I implemented information about who was modifying last, sucessfuly, but i dont get it with CreatedBy.
My model is

```
 public class TestModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Created { get;}
        public TestModel()
        {
            Created = DateTime.Now;
        }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    }
```

My controller of Create

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Description")] TestModel testModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(testModel);
                testModel.CreatedBy = this.User.Identity.Name;
               // testModel.ModifiedBy = this.User.Identity.Name;
                testModel.Modified = DateTime.Now;
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(testModel);
        }
```

Edit controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Description")] TestModel KestModel)
        {
            if (id != KestModel.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {

                  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!TestModelExists(KestModel.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }


            return View();
        }
```

Comment: are getting any exception specially for createdby?

Comment: Exception would be, i think with rule show only Specific Creater of an element. if i put in controller (create), createdby and modifiedby with =this.user.identity.name, it works, but if i edit item correct info. only about modifiedby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment I understood that you want to update modifyby on update request and assign createdby at the create request,

For this you should check the Id which is already assign or not, If id is already assign than it is update request else it is create request

Try below code changes

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Description")] TestModel testModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {                   
        if(testModel.Id > 0){
            // the entity is already created and it is modify request
            _context.Entry(testModel).State = EntityState.Modified;

            testModel.ModifiedBy = this.User.Identity.Name;
            testModel.Modified = DateTime.Now;
        }
        else{
            // it is create request
            _context.Entry(testModel).State = EntityState.Added;            

            testModel.CreatedBy = this.User.Identity.Name;
            testModel.Created = DateTime.Now;
        }            

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(testModel);
}
```

Comment: Not working ) he is erasing information of CreatedBy. I want implement the same way as Sharepoint do. If im in sharepoint create an element he will show me two dates (created,modified) if i edit element, only (modified column) will change.

Comment: he dont like (created)because i did already in model with only {get;}  _context.Entry(testModel).State = EntityState.Created;

                    testModel.CreatedBy = this.User.Identity.Name;
                    testModel.Created = DateTime.Now;

Comment: @vesperkg it should be `Added` instead of `Created`

Comment: testModel.Created = DateTime.Now; ( cannot assigned to -- it is read only) i will try to add get statement

Comment: with readonly i achieved the next. He will write correct information about creation date and of modifying date. But now i have problem with an edit controller can you check it please ? He not allowe to me to edit.